# Double input before Output

Tags: c

I'm having an issue with some code, where both my input prompts are running before the output, whereas the structure is here -

```
scanf("%d\n\n", &d);

printf("\nYour result is: %d. \nWhat is the random number?:", r * d);

scanf("%d\n\n", &s);
```

So whats occuring is that I get the first input prompt, then the second, then the printf runs. How would I fix it so scanf runs, then printf, then scanf again?

Full code for help -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int d;
int s;

int main() {

    //r for rand, d for dividing number, s for sum

    int r = rand() % 1 + 10;
    time_t SFE = time(NULL);
    srand(SFE);

    r = rand() % r;

    printf("Please choose a number: ");
    scanf("%d\n\n", &d);

    printf("\nYour result is: %d. \nWhat is the random number?:", r * d);

    scanf("%d", &s);

    if (s == r) {
        printf("\nYou have the correct number!");
        }
    else {
        printf("\nSorry, that's wrong. The correct answer is %d! Try again next time!", r);
        }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
 With such example, we will be able to reproduce your problem, understand it and try to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks user3121023

answer was just to remove the newlines.